# ACS package in R: Lots of missing counties

Tags: r, census

I am trying to find a clean way to pull some county-level census data into R, and I downloaded the acs package. I tried using the acs.fetch function to get some basic age/sex data for each county in Missouri. The function only gave back about 12 counties and Missouri has over 100.

I saw on a previous post that some counties might not have any data on a one-year ACS survey, but this seems like too many blanks. And, when I cross-checked this with a search for the same information in the American Fact Finder, it seemed like I was missing a lot in R. The code I tried is below.

```
library(acs)
acs.fetch(geography=geo.make(state="MO", county="*"), table.number ="B01003", endyear=2014, span=1)
```

Quick disclaimer: I am a beginner in R, and my vocabulary on the topic will be a bit limited.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran your snipped of code and saved it to variable `x` and there were indeed only 17 counties listed for that particular table. Just to be sure I then ran it as a 5-year estimate with a slight modification:

```
    library(acs)
  acs.fetch(geography=geo.make(state="MO", county="*"), table.number ="B01003", endyear=2014, span=5
```

When I did so, I received 115 counties:

```
str(x2@geography$NAME)
chr [1:115] "Adair County, Missouri" "Andrew County, Missouri" "Atchison County, Missouri" ..
```

So the single year estimate does not have what you are looking for at the county level, you will either need to adjust to work with 5-year estimates of find another source. But your code seems correct.
.